# Prime faces Export data not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces, data-export

I tried to export the data from my datatable but when I press the pdf button for example it refresh the page without export

```
   <h:commandLink  >
        <p:graphicImage value="/images/excel.png" />
        <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="dataTable" fileName="alarms" />
    </h:commandLink>

    <h:commandLink  >
        <p:graphicImage value="/images/pdf.png" />
        <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="dataTable"  fileName="alarms"/>
    </h:commandLink>

      <h:commandLink  >
        <p:graphicImage value="/images/csv.png" />
        <p:dataExporter type="csv" target="dataTable" fileName="alarms" />
    </h:commandLink>
```

Comment: Do you include right versions of itext and poi libraries in your project ?

Answer (score 0):

`<p:commandLink>` has to be surrounded by `<h:form>` tag to work. 
If this is not the problem can you please provide the source code of your whole page and the PrimeFaces version you are working with?

Answer (score 0):

```
<h:commandLink style=" text-align: right!important;"
    immediate="true" id="excelLinkId" ajax="false" >
        <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="myTable" fileName="myExcel" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Comment: please add more explanation to the code why the OP should use it, rather than dumping the code

Comment: With immediate="true" on the button, the action is indeed invoked during apply request values phase and all the remaining phases are skipped. That's also the sole point of this attribute: process (decode, validate, update and invoke) the component immediately during apply request values phase. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960718/trying-to-understand-immediate-true-skipping-inputs-when-it-shouldnt

Comment: good, now add this explanation into your answer by clicking on [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52256130/edit).