# Disable 'required' attribute on submit (or set it to false)

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I have a page built in JSF.

On it are some mandatory input fields.

I have two buttons - Submit & Cancel.

When a user hits Submit I want to ensure that everything is filled out, which works fine currently.

But when the user hits Cancel I want navigation to occur even though some of the inputs may be empty.

How can I achieve this?? Thanks!

Comment: BalusC's answer [here][1] should give you the info you need.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960718/trying-to-understand-immediate-true-skipping-validation-when-it-shouldnt

Comment: Unfortunately using the 'immediate' attribute doesn't work in this case as I'm using the t:saveState attribute to save the state of the session scoped bean backing the page. And for some reason this seems to save the view values even when I use immediate=true, so when I view the page again it contains the old partially filled values, even though the backing bean values have been updated.