# How to update p:inputText from backing bean?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to update `<p:inputText>` from backing bean after business logic is finished. 
I have two properties in backing bean `prop1` and `prop2`, and corresponding UI component as `<p:inputText>`. But when i update both ui component, they are not updated with the latest value from business logic. I tried to update using p:ajax and also with `RequestContext` but both are not working.

```
<p:inputText id="htmlDivs"
             style="display:inline"
             ajax="true"
             value="#{backingbean.deviceHtml}"/>

<p:inputText id="paths"
             style="display:inline"
             ajax="true"
             value="#{backingbean.connections}"/>
```

And

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(Arrays.asList("myform:htmlDivs",
                                                  "myform:paths",
                                                  "myform:devicePortTable"));
```

Strange thing is `devicePortTableis` updated. Any suggestion?

Thanks
Brijesh

Comment: how do you fire your action ?

Comment: this is how i am calling backing bean on button click <p:commandButton id="reloadSVGBtn"
       styleClass="pbutton" immediate="true" value="Hidden"
       actionListener="#{myform.reloadSVG}"
       update=":topologyViewForm:htmlDivs :topologyViewForm:paths">
       <p:ajax update=":topologyViewForm:htmlDivs :topologyViewForm:paths"/>
      </p:commandButton>

Comment: Did you try to remove `immediate` ? and also remove `<p:ajax>` ?

Comment: @Scorpion that solved my problem. Saved my day. immediate was culprit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove `immediate="true"` and also remove `<p:ajax>`cause it has no effect because you already has update attribute in your `<p:commandButton>`

```
 <p:commandButton id="reloadSVGBtn"
                  styleClass="pbutton"
                  value="Hidden"
                  actionListener="#{myform.reloadSVG}"
                  update=":topologyViewForm:htmlDivs :topologyViewForm:paths">  
</p:commandButton>
```

and for a further details read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960718/trying-to-understand-immediate-true-skipping-validation-when-it-shouldnt).