# How to update value of EditableValueHolder in action listener?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have this JSF (Java EE 7, provided by GlassFish 4.1 + PrimeFaces 5.1) form containing database connection information like host name, port number, etc. Also part of this form is a URL field. I want this field to be editable, but I also want to be able to set the value based on the other fields.

To do so I created a button with an action listener where I'm reading the posted data from the [request parameter map](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestParameterMap()) and generate the new URL value. Then I want to put the new value in the URL field and use that value instead of the posted data. What I tried is to get the component as [`EditableValueHolder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/EditableValueHolder.html) and set the submitted value and [render the response](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#renderResponse()). I also tried setting the component's value and calling [`resetValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/EditableValueHolder.html#resetValue()).

The best result was the URL field being updates after two clicks.

XHTML:

```
<p:inputText id="url"
             size="50"
             value="#{database.url}"/>
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w"
                 immediate="true"
                 actionListener="#{database.createConnectionURL('namingContainer')}">
  <p:ajax update="url" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Bean (using [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org/)):

```
UIComponent urlComponent = Faces.getViewRoot().findComponent(namingContainer + "url");
if (urlComponent instanceof EditableValueHolder) {
  EditableValueHolder editValHolder = (EditableValueHolder) urlComponent;
  editValHolder.setSubmittedValue(urlValue);
}
Faces.getContext().renderResponse();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `immediate="true"` is a leftover from JSF 1.x, when it was not possible to process only a specific set of inputs and/or buttons. It was then more than often abused to process only a specific set of inputs and/or buttons instead of to [prioritize validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960718/trying-to-understand-immediate-true-skipping-validation-when-it-shouldnt/12961162#12961162). You'd better not use it when you've JSF2 ajax at hands.

With JSF2 ajax you can just use `execute="..."` or in case of PrimeFaces `process="..."` to execute/process only a specific set of inputs/buttons.

```
<p:inputText id="url"
             size="50"
             value="#{database.url}" />
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w"
                 process="@this"
                 action="#{database.createConnectionURL('namingContainer')}" 
                 update="url" />
```

Then you can just update the model value.

```
public void createConnectionURL(String namingContainer) {
    // ...
    url = urlValue;
}
```

Note that I moved back `<p:ajax update>` into the `<p:commandButton>`. Perhaps you was mixing with `<h:commandButton>`.

#### See also:

- [Understanding PrimeFaces process/update and JSF f:ajax execute/render attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-process-and-update-attributes-of-primefaces/25347186#25347186)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, to deal with components with OmniFaces, better use [`Components`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/2.0/org/omnifaces/util/Components.html) utility class.

Comment: Well, that was amazingly simple :-). Indeed, in JSF 1.x this is a pain. Thanks again!